# Do I need to have a random split before my email activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I have a very simple journey, where I want to send an email to everyone out of 200k people that have provided an email address, so the audience is big. Do I have to have a random split before the email activity? Is it too much to send that many emails at once?

Thank you!!

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answers to your questions as accepted if they have been helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200k is not a big audience. You should be fine without a random split. If you want to delay your send throughput for some reason (e.g. you have a link in the email to your site, and you're afraid it will not be able to handle the traffic) you can use Send Throttling within [Email activity in JB](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5):

> Send Throttling - Select and set a delivery window and hourly
> threshold to set a maximum quantity of emails that can be sent each
> hour.

You can easily process up to 2M contacts per hour, if you adhere to [best practices in this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_optimize_sending_in_journey_builder.htm&type=5).